# GRUB file problem

Tags: grub2

When I try to update GRUB, I receive the following error:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

Here is my GRUB config:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Is this really the content of `/etc/default/grub`? Because there's no `)` character in line 1 like the error messages suggests. What's the output of `sh -n /etc/default/grub`, `head -n 1 /etc/default/grub` and `grep -nFe ')' /etc/default/grub`?

Comment: the output of grep -nFe ')' /etc/default/grub=13:# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
14:# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
17:# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)

Comment: Generating grub configuration file ...
/etc/grub.d/00_header: 30: .: Can't open /grub-mkconfig_lib
,,,,,this lines is generate when i try to run update-grub/sudo update-grub,,plz help me out

Comment: What is the exact command you type in to run `grub-mkconfig`? Do not include any output from the command in your answer. Only the exact characters you type in before you press enter.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please reinstall the `grub-common` package (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-common`) and try to update Grub again? Did anything change?

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between yours and my grub file is mine has

```
    # If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update       
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.      
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:      
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'
```

But that shouldnt make a difference since the lines are commented out. I had an update which updated grub that told me the grub files were different and I kept the one from the update and I no longer had the error you were getting. So i recommend you check fir any updates.

Please make sure you are showing the correct grub file output.

I am running 16.04 here is a copy of my grub file

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
  # This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that    obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via     VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

then you can use below to update

```
sudo update-grub
```